# Computation aborted without explanation

Tags: plotting

Mathematica aborts my computation and prints $Aborted after a while. What could be the possible reasons for this behavior and how can I figure out the precise cause?

The command is:

```
ParametricPlot[{{-\[Nu]^2, NIntegrate[Sparticle[p, I \[Nu]]*((1/4)  + (p^2))*(1/(2*\[Pi])), {p,0, \[Infinity]}]}, {\[Nu]^2, NIntegrate[Sparticle[p, \[Nu]]*((1/4)  + (p^2))*(1/(2*\[Pi])), {p,0, \[Infinity]}]}}, {\[Nu], 0, 4}, AspectRatio -> .5,PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.001], Red}, {Thickness[0.001], Red}}]
```

The above command works fine when the range of the plot is set to `{\[Nu], 0, 2}`.

Comment: Did you check the memory consumption by MMa during the evaluation of your code?

Comment: I just did with MaxMemoryUsed. It says 0.13 GB. I have a 4 GB system with around 2 GB free.

Comment: Did it show 0.13Gb after crash? Or did you use it with dynamic refresh?
I've tested your code in MMa 11.3, it produces the error message: NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand ((1/4+p^2) Sparticle[p,0. +0.0000816327 I])/(2 \[Pi]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.}}.   Can you provide the `Sparticle` ?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how to make it dynamic. Sparticle is big and the plot could take upto an hour, depending on your system, but if you like [here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hifr02nj1yq8209/sparticle.nb?dl=0) a link to it.

Comment: Do you want explanations of why your code aborts or do you want alternatives of your code that produce the desired plot?

Comment: I am primarily interested in getting the plot.

Comment: @cord, At first, I recommend you to wrap your equation by `N[..]`. Because even simple `Sparticle[0,0]` produces result too long time and it is very complicated visually with a lot of symbols like Pi which are not floating point numbers. It decreases the calculations. The second is you should try the preliminary simplification of the formula before calculations. Finally, the compiled function will be much faster than usual one. So, let's try `Sparticle[..]=Compile[...]`.

Comment: @Rom38 That worked! Took several hours, but got the plot finally. Thanks.